# How to config Outgoing WS-Security in Postman?

Tags: postman

The request works in SoapUI but as we are using Postman-Newman for Automation of this API so how to make this work in Postman.

I saw some solutions where it says to add security tag in request body but what's the username to provide there as we don't provide any user name in SoapUI.

How I config in SoapUI

1. Select Keystores and select the certificate and add password
2. Set "Outgoing WS-Security Configurations" attaching screenshot to show what we have to send in that. keystore, password, key identifier Type and parts

[image]

Postman config:

1. Added the certificate in postman using settings as well added the password.
2. Created a request and added the request body

in request body I tried below but I am not sure what is the username or nonce as we don't give this info in SoapUI. This returns an error `The SOAP request has not been signed, or is signed incorrectly`

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id='TS-11b7d3261c994de099eb8c431b33947b'>
<wsu:Created>2019-09-06T12:09:15.604Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2019-09-06T12:09:25.619Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id='UsernameToken-238be95be3bf445fb8534666a7a8693c'>
<wsse:Username>***login***</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-usernametoken-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest'>***Base64 (SHA-1 (nonce + created + password) )***</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soapmessage-security-1.0#Base64Binary'>***Base64 nonce***</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2019-09-06T12:09:15.604Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Also tried below and here I get soap fault

```
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

Also tried below solution but not sure what username to provide here as we only provide Password in SoapUI and not UserName

```
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>Whattogivehere</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>******</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the WS-Security header part in your soap header like bellow. Also please make sure to enter the correct Username and Password as plaintext.

```
 <soapenv:Header>
       ------

>     <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
>          <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-16" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
>             <wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>
>             <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXXX</wsse:Password>
>          </wsse:UsernameToken>
>       </wsse:Security>

      ----
 </soapenv:Header>
```